# EF Core 3.1 Linq Query Failed - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Boolean'

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am upgrding an asp.net core web site from 2.2 to 3.1. and am experiencing the below issue:

This code is just to extract data from db, using ef like this

```
 var dealer = _context.Dealers.Include(e => e.Vehicles)
                              .Include(e => e.VolumePlans)
                              .First(e => e.ID == user.DealerID);
```

It fails saying:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Boolean'

and calling stack info:

> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Boolean()
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetBoolean(Int32 i)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` in linq query